# Non stationary residuals from stationary regression

Tags: regression, time-series, linear

I was wondering, if I perform linear OLS regression with stationary (verified) time series $y_t$ on $x_{1t}$,$x_{2t}$:

- can the residuals be non-stationary?
- it is not  part of a list of Gauss-Markov assumption that the residuals of the OLS linear regression must be stationary so we usually don't need to perform stationarity test on *residuals* as a part of time series linear OLS regression?

Comment: You can always fit an ARIMA model to your residuals. Rob Hyndman explains this in his blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/), which [has been referenced a few times on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ARIMAX+model+muddle%22).

Comment: "Verified" stationarity includes also homoskedasticity separately for the dependent variable and the regressors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your independent variables are non-stationary and the dependent variable is then the residuals will end up being non-stationary.

Gauss-Markov conditions [require stationary of residuals](http://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/312/tschapters/S13_Ch_2.pdf) for time series.

Comment: But what if all my time series are stationary? And in the list of assumptions i don't see explicitly stationary of residuals as requirement. I believe i don't understand something.

Comment: @AlexanderShubert, the requirements of Gauss MArkov do not spell it out literally, but the residuals are stationary. For instance, TS-4 in my link tells you that the variance is constant, which is one of the conditions of stationary series